# How to log from command and control log level using debug/warning/error?

Tags: sbt

After reading the [documentation about logging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/logging.html) in SBT, I know how to log from a task by means of `streams.value.log`.  I do it extensively.  But what about logging from a custom command?

In a command we have available the [state](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.State), and the only interesting thing for logging is [globalLogging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.GlobalLogging), but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `State` class has a `log` member, added through some implicit magic, that you can use. Without the implicit magic you can use the explicit `globalLogging` member to access the `full` logger.

Example:

```scala
def hello = Command.command("hello") { state =>
  // These are equivalent
  state.log.info("Hello!")
  state.globalLogging.full.info("Hello!")

  state
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** I'm mostly guessing, but comments section would not have been appropriate either.

sbt **0.13.8-M2** here.

I'm using the following `hello` command in `build.sbt` to get at `streams.value.log`:

```
val hello: Command = Command.command("hello") { (s: State) =>
    val extracted: Extracted = Project.extract(s)
    import extracted._

    // streams.value.log
    val Value(v) = Project.evaluateTask(streams in currentRef, s).get
    println(v.log)
    s
}

commands += hello
```

However, the `v` is initialized it appears it's too late to use it or it's not for commands and hence the following stacktrace:

```
[sbt-learning-space]> hello
java.lang.RuntimeException: Streams for '{file:/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/}sbt-learning-space/*:streams' have been closed.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.checkOpen(Streams.scala:146)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.make(Streams.scala:127)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.text(Streams.scala:113)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log(Streams.scala:124)
    at $129b92cf2e7230691a78$$anonfun$1.apply(build.sbt:71)
    at $129b92cf2e7230691a78$$anonfun$1.apply(build.sbt:64)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:29)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:29)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Streams for '{file:/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/sbt-learning-space/}sbt-learning-space/*:streams' have been closed.
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

My understanding is that commands are outside the scope of `streams.value.log` as they're to configure `state` for settings.

Comment: Thanks Jacek, I didn't know that possibility.  It deserves to be further explored, when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is simply with `println()`, but you don't have control about the log level (`debug`, `warning`, `error`).